# Retry processing logic in spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

I am developing a spring batch application.I want to retry processor logic.As in processor,I have some db tables to monitor,i want to update some other tables depending on these monitored table.Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retry items by using a [fault tolerant step](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/step.html#retryLogic). You can configure which exception to retry and the retry limit. Here is an example:

```
@Bean
public Step faultTolerantStep() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("faultTolerantStep")
                            .<String, String>chunk(2)
                            .reader(itemReader())
                            .processor(itemProcessor())
                            .writer(itemWriter())
                            .faultTolerant()
                            .retryLimit(3)
                            .retry(MyTransientException.class)
                            .build();
}
```

In this example, when a `MyTransientException` is thrown from the processor or writer, the item will be retried at most 3 times.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i dont want to retry incase of exception..I just want to repeat processor logic to monitor DB state

Comment: In that case, don't call it "retry" in your question. Retrying something implies that you tired it first, and that you want to retry it because of an error in the first attempt, at least that what it means in Spring Batch semantics. What you can do in your case is use a scheduled task that your run repeatedly (every 10s for example) to monitor your table and act accordingly.